# idangerous page navigation but not a single slide

Tags: jquery

Нi all. How to show only the navigation pages but not the slides?
I have 20 slides to 4 on a page, and idangerous displays all 20 points. How to show 4? Thanks.

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
    pagination: '.pagination',
    paginationClickable: true,
    slidesPerView: 4
  })
```

Example 
http://jsfiddle.net/ELwkt/1/

Comment: Not quite clear about what you want but I guess leaving the first point for each view visible and hiding the rest will do the job for you (Basically keep only [1,5,9,13,17] visible and hide the rest using CSS [nth-child selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp).

Comment: Make a jsfiddle.. its easy for debug..!

Answer (score 1):

I thinks this works better:

```js
new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
  paginationClickable: true,
  paginationBulletRender: function (index, className) {
    // Four slides per view
    if (index % 4 > 0) {
      className += " hidden"; // added hidden class
    }

    return '<span class="' + className + '"></span>';
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to you all! Used a variant with css (from srvikram13) because a short time.

Also offered such variant =)

```
var f = function(a, b) {
$.each($('.swiper-pagination-switch'), function(i, e) {
    if (i % 2) {
        if ($(e).hide().hasClass('swiper-active-switch'))
            $(e).prev().addClass('swiper-active-switch');
    }
});
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    pagination: '.pagination',
    paginationClickable: true,
    simulateTouch: true,
    grabCursor: true,
    mode:'horizontal',
    slidesPerView:2,
    onSlideChangeStart: f,
    onSlideChangeStop: f,
    onInit: f,
 })
```

It would be a kosher way )))